# Boost.Asio How to send "hello world" to my website

Tags: html, server, client, boost-asio

I am teaching myself website programming and server/client programming.

I have just finished daytime server/client (tutorial posted at https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html).

I have my own website http://blu3bug.com/

It is hosted by bluehost.

My ultimate goal is making "account creation/log in system" for my website.

But for now I want to run a server on my machine then have my http://blu3bug.com/ visitors to connect to my machine then get daytime information.

As a first step of doing so, I want to know how to set up my website so that it connect to my IP address.

Comment: if this is about configuring DNS, see [SF]. If it is about configuring a web server, see e.g. https://askubuntu.com or similar.